# How to catch chmod Operation not permitted error in PHP?

Tags: php, chmod

> Warning: chmod(): Operation not permitted in /var/www/html/

1. How to catch chmod operation not permitted error or warning in PHP?
2. How to check if we have permission to execute chmod command in PHP?
3. How to check if chmod command executed successfully in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping it in `try .. catch`? It would solve all 3

Comment: Since when `chmod` __throws__ errors/exceptions?

Comment: And also check return status of `chmod`

Comment: @Justinas chmod doesn't throw any Exception. Also, it returns true in a warning. "Operation not permitted" is a warning somehow not an error as per PHP. I don't know why

Comment: #2, testing whether you have permission, is complicated but not impossible. You have to figure out your user, the user's groups and compare that with the file's groups. #1, you should be able to suppress with `@` and check the result if it failed to know that you had a problem. #3 is the most trickiest probably, because if a file has, for instance, `755` on it, but you don't have permission to change things AND want to change it to `755`, your code will fail but the permission will be correct.